# Pass Custom Java Objects to a Shared Native Library

Tags: android, shared-libraries, lib

I was recently given shared libraries (.so files) to incorporate into our Android application.

Along with the shared libraries I was given a few Java classes and the following file, that offers me some Java methods to call when I want to call the library methods:

```java
    public native long doSomething(String str, int i, int i2, int i3, boolean b);

    public native Result doAnotherThing(CustomObject obj);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("DoSomethingLib");
    }
```

There are, of course, a lot more methods than in the example above. After some testing I figured out, that all the methods that only receive and return base types (int, byte, boolean, String, etc). work like a charm. So the linking to the library and all is working.
However, all methods that take custom Java objects, like the second one in the example above, return null.

I am assuming that the library is not able to handle these custom Java objects correctly.

How does the .so library know how to treat the custom Java objects that I pass to the native calls? Am I missing something? Do I have to tell the .so library where it can find my Java objects somehow? Or should all of this be handled inside the library itself?

Is there a way to find out why the library is not happy with the objects I pass to it?

I do not have access to the library source code.

Comment: Did you get `CustomObject` as part of the API to the library and how are you calling into the library with the CustomObject ?

Comment: Yes, they provided CustomObject.java along with their library. CustomObject is passed to the library via a call to `doAnotherThing()` (in the example above).